# How to set background color width of dropdown menu items in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have the following navigation bar: http://jsfiddle.net/jajq3/embedded/result/

For posterity, this is the structure:

```
<div id="navBar">
    <ul style="float: left; padding-left: 5px;">
        <li>
            <a href="#">A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">C</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">This is a thing.</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cool man</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Linus</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">D</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Gerg.</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">asdf idiot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blah</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, when you hover over a dropdown menu link, the background color behind the link changes. But in IE7, the background does not extend all the way to the edge of the dropdown menu; it only goes to the edge of the link's text. In modern browsers, this is not observed. So how can I get this working in IE7?

Before answering, please note that I do not want to explicitly set a width for the dropdown menu. Currently, the dropdown menu links dictate how wide the dropdown menu will be, and this is how I want it to remain. (for example, the dropdown menu for D should always be wider than C's because it has that really long "Weeeeeeeeee" link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the styles set on `#navBar > ul > li > ul > li` and just let the list items be list items. Then they automatically are as wide as their containing `ul`.

Then if you set  the `background-color` on `:hover` on the `li` instead of on the `a`, the `background-color` fills up the whole width of the menu.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle embedded result link**](http://jsfiddle.net/jajq3/2/embedded/result/)</kbd> which will work in IE7.

Get rid of this bit of **CSS**:

<strike>`#navBar > ul > li > ul > li
    {
        width: 100%;
        clear: left;
        display: block;
    }`</strike>

And split the class at the bottom of your CSS into two parts:

```
#navBar > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover
{
    background-color: #999;
}
#navBar > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a
{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, although I found that simply removing the `width: 100%` from `#navBar > ul > li > ul > li` also worked.

Comment: No worries, I didn't think of that, I guess you would want the `a` element to fill up the whole width anyway, so then you might as well keep the `background-color` on the `a` element, as the user can then click on the whole list item to navigate instead of only on the link. I must have been tired, not thinking straight, it's good you got it fixed though :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a custom IE7 stylesheet to your project and add special padding.

```
<!-- [if IE 7]>
<style rel="text/css">
  myMenu li {

     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I don't understand how extra padding will make each dropdown link's background extend to the edge of the dropdown menu? And what is `myMenu`?